# Populating hidden customfield via python jira

Tags: jira-rest-api, python-jira

I´m using the python jira package to create and update issues in our self hosted Jira. Sometimes it happens, that issues are created without filling in all information. Because of that, customfields are empty after the creation.
Later, people want to update some fields that were empty before, because now they have new information.

This is not working, I get the error:
`"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"customfield_100233":"Field 'customfield_100233' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown."}}`

I guess this happens because the field is hidden and therefor can´t be updated, because it currently has an empty value.

Has somebody an idea, how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Jira Dropdown Fields can´t be updated to None via a value, you have to set the id to -1.